# How to get User model field inside Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am using asp.net core with Identity. For user I have this class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get Rates inside Razor, how can this be done with the Name field (User.Identity.Name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, please confirm whether you have successfully added a `one to many` relation of `Rate table` for Identityuser and generated the Rate
> table in the database.

Please **change all Identityuser references** (except where the User class inherits) in your project **to your customized User class**, including the relevant view page and the startup class.

And then change the ApplicationDbContext as follow:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public DbSet<Rate> Rate { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
       
    }
```

Then **excute migration command**. More details, refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NV734cJdZts).

Here is my Rate Class:

```
  public class Rate
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int rate { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

After completing the above operations, `add relevant Rates data` to the database.

Then start the project, log in the user information, and then use the following code in the corresponding action and view to show Rates of associated Name field:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context; 

    public AccountController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    { 
        var rates = await _context.Rate.Include(host => host.User).Where(x => x.User.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync();
        return View(rates);
    }
}
```

Razor View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Rate>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}

<h1>Index</h1>

UserName: @User.Identity.Name  related Rates data:
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.rate</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]